# Responsive HTML/CSS tree view

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, tree, treeview

I want to build responsive tree diagram - basic example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ppnfpggx/2/

But with the responsive layout I have some problems. For example, on small device it should looks like this:[image]

Above line of each item:

```
.tree-item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -20px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 88px; // (48 + 20 + 20 -> half-margin on both sides)
}
```

The items count may be dynamic, so I tried playing with `:last-child` to remove `::before`, but have problems with item before last. What I really need when items count more than three, the 3rd item should closing the tree, remove from remaining items `pseudo-elements` and somehow center last two items without `margin-left`.

Can I achieve this responsive view by CSS/JS, if yes, please provide any idea or basic example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you want, but flexing is often a good way to make responsive design with only css.

```css
#tree{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

//Edit
Try to put this block of code in to your css. Not working perfectly, but solves the initial problem.

```css
@media (max-width: 340px) {
    .tree-item:nth-child(n+4)::before {
        display: none;
        }
    .tree-item:nth-child(n+4)::after {
    display: none;
    }
    .tree-item:nth-child(3)::after {
      left: auto;
      right: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, flexbox is cool stuff for responsive, but I really want to remove `::before` and `::after` from last and pre-last childs and make it suit for all cases(please see screen above)